# Passport object does not exist in session object in production environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, passport.js, express-session

The passport object is non existent on my session object. It works as expected in my local environment, but when I move to my production server on aws, there is no passport object. The session is getting stored in my dynamoDB store successfully, but it's not showing up in the req.

Here's what I expect in the req.session object(and what I'm getting in my local env):

```
session: 
   Session {
     cookie: 
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true },
     passport: { user: [Object] } } <------- This Object
```

Here is what I'm getting in production:

```
 session: 
       Session {
         cookie: 
          { path: '/',
            _expires: null,
            originalMaxAge: null,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false } }
    ---------No sign of the passport object---------
```

Server set up:

```
// DynamoDBStore Configuration
const options = {
  table: 'capture-sessions',
  AWSConfigJSON: {
    accessKeyId: awsConfig.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
    region: 'us-east-2'
  }
};

app.use(cors());

app.use(expressSession({
  store: new DynamoDBStore(options),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true
  }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./passport/init')(passport);
```

Comment: What is your deployment model in AWS ?

Comment: It's just a basic EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing a remote/production site and it's using `https` you need to have `secure :true`. right now I see in your code it says secure is false. You can use something like this.

```
    cookie: { 
        secure : process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false
   }
```